# Print with absolute fixed positions from website (html/css) without system borders from print dialog

Tags: html, css, printing

I have a little problem with printing a website.
I need to print on a fixed sticker sheet in A4 format:
https://www.avery-zweckform.com/search?term=L6009&content_group=ALL_CONTENT_GROUPS

To match exactly the stickers on this A4 sheet I need a fixed A4 CSS grid.

When I use a fixed size in centimeters then this is working but when I try to print this page (Chrome & Firefox the same) there is always a small border added from the browser itself.

Example:
After printing I have a padding-right of 3cm instead of my defined 2cm.
On the left side I have 2,5cm and on the top 3cm again.

So it seems it is not possible to create an exacte sheet to print what is really disappointing.

Had anyone an idea or the same problem?

HTML

```
<page size="A4">
    <div class="inner">
      <div style="width: 100%; height: 30px; background-color: grey"></div>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy
      eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam
      voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet
    </div>
</page>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  background: rgb(204, 204, 204);
}
page[size="A4"] {
  background: white;
  width: 21cm;
  height: 29.7cm;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 0.5cm;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.5cm rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.inner {
  padding: 2cm;
}

@media print {
  body {
    margin: 0 !important;
  }
  page[size="A4"] {
    margin: 0 !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
  }
  @page {
    size: auto;
    margin: 0mm;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try reseting margin and padding for all elementes first and just user your custom values.
I'm not sure if it works in your case, but try it in the beginning of your css:

```
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

I hope it can useful for you.

Comment: In PDF print that seems to work. I will give you feedback if it also works for real printing. Thanks until now!

Comment: Perfect @BjörnEnders